# What is the runic inscription on Finn's mug?

Tags: adventure-time

At the beginning of the *Adventure Time* episode [*Card Wars*](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Wars) we can see Finn drinking from a wooden mug with runic inscriptions:

[image: Finn eating a sandwich with a clear glass and a brown mug with a runic inscription on the table]

I've tried my best to figure out what those runes are, and my googling headed me to Wikipedia (Adventure Time Wikia doesn't mention the mug nor the runes).

In order of appearance in the mug I've identified the runes below:

---

**__ᚦ**

**_ᚠ**

**ᛗᚨᚿ_**

**_ᛚᛖ**

---

Which seems to be some [Elder Futhark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elder_Futhark) runes. But even if I can identify some runes, the meaning is a mistery for me.

Does anyone know what the meaning of the inscriptions is and from where Finn got this mug?

Comment: I believe it says "cup of many ale", but not exactly. So I post this as a comment instead of an answer. At least you know what I think.

Comment: Do you know which are the runes I couldn't identify?

Comment: It's not Elder Futhark due to the last rune of the third word. It's most likely Anglo-Saxon. With my previous comment, you can riddle it out. The last rune of the first word should be P but evaluates to "TH". But I have a theory about that. Any more and you are asking me to post an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look! It's also green:

[image: Finn pouring brown liquid out of the mug in green into one of many glasses on the table]

And the information on all the runes in the series is in the [Adventure Time Wiki](https://adventuretime.fandom.com/wiki/Runic_code).

The wiki cites [a Spring.me post](https://archive.is/YfLRE), where character designer
Andy Ristaino (skronked) said:

> i'm not totally sure i'm remembering correctly, but i think it's supposed to say "cup of many ales", or maybe "pitcher of many ales". it's a magical object that could pour out any sort of liquid.

Here are the individual letters, which I individually linked to Wikipedia pages:

[ᚳ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaunan)[ᚢ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ur_(rune))p [ᚩ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansuz_(rune))[ᚠ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fehu) [ᛗ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mannaz)[ᚫ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansuz_(rune))[ᚿ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Dalrunor.svg)[ᚣ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runes#/media/File:Anglosaxonrunes.svg) [ᚫ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansuz_(rune))[ᛚ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguz)[ᛖ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehwaz)

The "p" looks like thorn (þ), but "th" doesn't make sense here so it's obviously supposed to be a "p". I also don't think that they're from the same set of futhark, as you can see on the Wikipedia pages. Taking everything into account, it says **"cup of many ale"**.

Comment: Congratulations, this is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4417/49).